# Search using PDF Open Parameters sometimes fails

Tags: url, search, pdf, parameters, adobe

I'm opening PDF files with search highlighting in embedded Acrobat by using the "search" open parameter in a URL.

Example:

```
http://example.org/doc.pdf#search="foo"
```

Sometimes this works (PDF opens with results highlighted) and sometimes it does not (PDF opens without results highlighted).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out that the cause of the failure was the file extension being uppercase.

For example, the URL in the question would work but the following would fail:

```
http://example.org/doc.PDF#search="foo"
```

The solution was to change the file extension to lowercase .pdf, but if anyone has a better solution, I will gladly accept a different answer.

Comment: I am trying to do the same thing. I am also able to do the search. But it will be very helpful if you kindly let me know how to search the keyword in a particular page. Say page no 3 or page 2-3. In Current situation the search is for the hole document.